# Accessing SQLite from Activity, Async and Service

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-service

I am reading first 100 SMS from inbox and store it in local database. I am doing this with the help on AsyncTask. Afterwards I am reading those SMS from local database and display it. In onPostExecute of AysncTask after reading & storing first 100 SMS, I am invoking the service to read the remaining SMS and storing it in local database. Till before invoking the service, UI is responsive but after invoking the service, the UI became unresponsive. Is it due to database lock or something else. Please help to solve this problem...

My AsyncTask code

```
private class InitialSetup extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
        fetchSMS();
        updateDatabase();
        return 0L;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
        populateUI(getApplicationContext());
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SMSService.class);
        getApplication().startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Service code

```
public class SMSService extends Service {

    Long inboxSMSID, localSMSID;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        if (intent.hasExtra("InboxSMS") && intent.hasExtra("SMSID")) {
            inboxSMSID = intent.getLongExtra("InboxSMS", 0);
            localSMSID = intent.getLongExtra("SMSID", 0);
            globalToLocalSMSDB(inboxSMSID);
        }
    }

    private void globalToLocalSMSDB(Long id) {
        SMSTable smsObj = new SMSTable(getApplicationContext());
        smsObj.open();
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor smscur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null,
                "_id < " + id, null, "_id DESC");
        while (smscur.moveToNext()) {
            String sender = SMSManagement.getSender(smscur);
            String message = SMSManagement.getMessage(smscur);
            String timeStamp = SMSManagement.getTime(smscur);
            smsObj.insertIntoSMSTable(sender, message, timeStamp);
        }
        smscur.close();
        smsObj.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends what your are doing in your service. Paste its code too

Comment: Are you creating *several* instances of your SQLiteOpenHelper? Try using a singleton pattern - and either synchronize it yourself or enable thread safety on the db.

Comment: see why are you not accessing the remaining sms from asyntask and why u need service ... and if so you are using please release the data connection and content resolver and recreate it in service or show  me your logcat when your apps become unresponsive

Comment: @VipinSahu I tried using async also. It still remains the same

Comment: @Jens Can you please explain it further?. Also can you give me any link which shows the usage of singleton pattern in terms of SQLite(if possible with multiple tables)

Answer (score 0):

The service is running in UI thread as well, you have to create worker threads there manually unless it's an IntentService.

Comment: I tried invoking in doInBackground() but again UI became unresponsive

Comment: nono... it doesn't matter how you invoke a service, new threads must be created inside of it (i. e. in onStartCommand)

Comment: hey without your code of service it hard to tell what is the real problem ... but if are facing a locking problem with data just have this link https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ftouchlab%2FAndroid-Database-Locking-Collisions-Example&ei=QCWRT4zOOM7PrQfW6-yKBQ&usg=AFQjCNF2tulc8Ep4xa_F0GUWGKxsAyCkDg&sig2=VDitPzBZYFp05V2nL0BYuw&cad=rja

Comment: have to tried to debug the code when you start your service and is your service is getting started or might have context problem ....

Comment: You are obviously running all your code in UI thread. You need to explicitly start a thread in a service OR use IntentService which IMO suits your need perfectly.

Comment: Just try implementing IntentService and in its onHandleIntent method do exactly what you're doing with your extras and SMS